# If a connection on a principal $G$-bundle restricts to an $H$-subbundle, must its holonomy lie in $H$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, principal-bundles, holonomy

Let $P \to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle, equipped with a principal connection $D$.

Let $Q \subset P$ be a principal subbundle with fiber $H$, where $H \leq G$ is a (let's say closed and connected) Lie subgroup.

> **Question:** Suppose that $D$ restricts to a principal connection on $Q$.  Does it follow that $\text{Hol}(D)$ is a subgroup of $H$?

As usual, this is not a homework question, but simply me trying to better organize my understanding.

[This question asked 11 days ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654520/connection-on-a-restricted-bundle) (which has received little attention) is essentially asking the same thing, but is more optimistic.

Comment: Yes. In fact there as a “smallest” reduction to which $D$ restricts, whose fibre type is $\operatorname{Hol}(D)$, called the _holonomy bundle_.

Comment: @canaaerus Cool! Could you make your comment an answer, and perhaps provide either details and/or references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is essentially "yes". More precisely, $\text{Hol}(D)$ is only well-defined up to conjugation in $G$ and the statement is that if $D$ restricts to some $H$ subbundle $Q\subset P$  then $\text{Hol}(D)$ is the conjugacy class of a subgroup of $H$.

This is an  immediate consequence of the definitions of the terms involved (the Theorem of Ambrose-Singer is not necessary). Here is a quick sketch of the argument (mostly uncovering definitions).

A connection $D$ on a prinicipal $G$-bundle $\pi:P\to M$ is given by a distribution $\mathcal H\subset TP$, $G$-invariant and transversal to the fibers of $P\to M$. 
The holonomy of $D$  is defined by picking a base point $p\in P$, then for each closed curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=\pi(p)$, you first lift it horizontally to the unique  curve $\tilde\gamma:[0,1]\to P$ such that $\gamma=\pi\circ\tilde\gamma$, $\tilde\gamma(0)=p$ and ${d\over dt}\tilde\gamma\in\mathcal H$, then its holonomy is defined to be the element $h\in G$ such that $\tilde\gamma(1)=\tilde\gamma(0)h.$ Then $\text{Hol}(D,p)\subset G$ is the set of all holonomies of all such $\gamma$.

If you switch to another base point instead of $p$ then it follows immediately from the $G$-invariance of $\mathcal H$ that $\text{Hol}(D,p)$ gets conjugated, hence $\text{Hol}(D)$ is only well defined up to conjugation.

If $Q\subset P$ is an $H$-subbundle, where $H\subset G$ is a subgroup, then "$D$ restricts to $Q$"  means that $\mathcal H$ is tangent to $Q$, i.e. $\mathcal H|_Q\subset TQ$. In particular, if you pick a base point $q\in Q$, all lifted $\tilde\gamma$ remain in $Q$ hence $\text{Hol}(D,q)\subset H$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ denote the basepoint for the holonomy group.  The Ambrose-Singer theorem says that the Lie algebra of the holonomy group of $D$ is the subspace of the Lie algebra of $G$ spanned by elements of the form $\Omega_q(X,Y)$ where $q$ is a point in the holonomy bundle at $p$, $X$ and $Y$ are horizontal tangent vectors at $q$, and $\Omega$ is the curvature of $D$.  If $D$ restricts to $Q$ then its curvature lies in the Lie algebra of $H$, so by exponentiation the holonomy group is a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Ah, so simple, thanks!